# I don't understand the (doc fn)...it says I can name a function, but I can't invoke it by its name?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and am grasping to understand the concepts. The REPL helpfully lets me get docs of "stuff".  So I want to define a function...

```
clojure-noob.core> (doc fn)
-------------------------
clojure.core/fn
  (fn name? [params*] exprs*)
  (fn name? ([params*] exprs*) +)
Special Form
  ...
  name => symbol
```

...and the doc suggests that I can name my function.  The REPL accepts my function, but I can't invoke it, "Unable to resolve symbol.."...

```
clojure-noob.core> (fn add-pair [a b] (+ a b))
#<core$eval3364$add_pair__3365 clojure_noob.core$eval3364$add_pair__3365@6fb5a33b>
clojure-noob.core> (add-pair 1 2)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: add-pair in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/1g/fnytl2x93sx6hp2f1rsf4h1r5xtqv_/T/form-init6828995349142227131.clj:1:1) 
clojure-noob.core>
```

Leaving off the name and building a proper def of the fn does get the job done as does leveraging the defn macro thing...

```
clojure-noob.core> (def another-add-pair (fn [a b] (+ a b)))
clojure-noob.core> (another-add-pair 1 2)
3
clojure-noob.core> (defn yet-another-add-pair [a b] (+ a b))
#'clojure-noob.core/yet-another-add-pair
clojure-noob.core> (yet-another-add-pair 3 4)
7
```

There is obviously something I don't understand about the output of `(doc fn)`.  In particluar, what is the `name?` there and what can you do with it?  I am as much trying to learn how to read the docs as well as understand the fn special form.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

calling `(fn add-pair [a b] (+ a b))` from the REPL builds an instance of that function and then prints it to the screen. After that it goes away and **is not saved anywhere**. This is why you can't get it's docs using the `doc` function. The name parameter in the `fn` literal is often used for making recursive calls and does not mean that it will be saved by that name anywhere.

if you call `(defn add-pair [a b] (+ a b))` then it **saves the function into the namespace** and then the `doc` function is able to look it up later and print it's doc string.

Comment: the name arg for `fn` is also used to make stacktraces more readable, and make it easier to identify which anonymous fn saw an error

Comment: s/only/often/ ... fixed ;-)

Comment: @noisesmith Aha!  That's it.  I see.

Comment: The repl usually binds the last three evaluated things to *1 *2 and *3 so it is not true that it is not saved anywhere.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin `(clojure.repl/doc *1)` => `"clojure.core/*1 bound in a repl thread to the most recent value printed"` so it is not applicable to *this* question. It describes the `*1` value it's self rather than it's current contents.

Comment: You must have misread the question. It is surprising that your answer was accepted anyway. The question is why he can't invoke the function, not why he can't look up its docstring.

Comment: @Thumbnail Why don't you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

- A `fn` form evaluates to a *function object*.
- You can apply the function object immediately:

  `((fn [a b] (+ a b)) 1 1) ;=> 2`
- If you want to refer to the function object locally, use a `let`
  binding:

  `(let [add-pair (fn [a b] (+ a b))] (add-pair 1 1)) ;=> 2`
- A function object is as much a value as `1`
  or `[3 :a]`:

  `(let [double (fn [n] (* 2 n))]
    (({double (comp double double)} double) 3)
   ;=> 12`
- The `let` binding does not exist within the `fn` form - you need a
  name parameter for that:

  `((fn fact [n] (case n, 0 1, (* n (fact (dec n))))) 5) ;=> 120`
- `letfn` does both:

  `(letfn [(fact [n] (case n, 0 1, (* n (fact (dec n)))))] (fact 5)) ;=> 120`
- If you want the function to be accessible globally, bind it to a
  `var` using `def`:

  `(def fact (fn fact [n] (case n, 0 1, (* n (fact (dec n))))))`

  `(fact 5) ;=> 120`
- The `defn` macro does the same more succinctly:

  `(defn fact [n] (case n, 0 1, (* n (fact (dec n)))))`

  `(fact 5) ;=> 120`